# Remove height value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, responsive-design

I have created a responsive site and then used some JS code to create captions on the images which works fine but when I re-size the browser. The images don't scale like they should and I believe its due to being given a height value in the JS. How do I remove this value and make the caption work?

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
   // For each instance of p.caption
   $("p.caption").each(function(){
     $(this)
        // Add the following CSS properties and values
        .css({
             // Height equal to the height of the image
            "height" : $(this).children("img").height() + "px",
            // Width equal to the width of the image
            "width" : $(this).children("img").width() + "px"
        })
        // Select the child "span" of this p.caption
        // Add the following CSS properties and values
        .children("span").css(

            // Width equal to p.caption
            // But subtract 20px to callibrate for the padding
            "width", $(this).width() - 20 + "px")

        // find the <big> tag if it exists
        // And then add the following div to break the line
        .find("big").after('<div class="clear"></div>');

        // When you hover over p.caption
        $("p.caption").hover(function(){

            // Fade in the child "span"
            $(this).children("span").stop().fadeTo(400, 1);
            }, function(){
            // Once you mouse off, fade it out
            $(this).children("span").stop().delay(600).fadeOut(400);
        });
    // End $(this)   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try window.resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("p.caption").each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
        var big = item.find("big");

        item.css({
            "height" : item.children("img").height() + "px",
            "width" : item.children("img").width() + "px"
        }).children("span").css("width", item.width() - 20 + "px");
    });
});
```

I refactored your code and created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VinnyFonseca/6Kv9U/1/

Comment: thanks for this. I just noticed that when you shrink the browser, it resizes perfectly but when you increase the browser size the images don't scale. Is there another resize function to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.resize()` will solve this for you http://api.jquery.com/resize/

You just have to store that procedural code to be re-executable (function) and then retrigger it based on relative (parent) DOM dimensions.

```
'use strict';

removeHeight(){
    // That code here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Initial removal
    removeHeight();

    // Removal when resizing
    $(window).resize(function() { removeHeight() });
});
```